# rewrite url's without the second variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url that can be any of the below:

```
1.  example.com/index/var1=word&var2=word&var3=number&var4=number&var5=word&var6=word&page=number
2.  example.com/index/var1=word&var2=word&var3=number&var4=number&var5=word&var6=word
3.  example.com/index/var1=word&var3=number&var4=number&var5=word&var6=word&page=number
4.  example.com/index/var1=word&var3=number&var4=number&var5=word&var6=word
```

This is my current htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\?var1=([^&\s]+)&var2=([^&\s]+)&var3=([^&\s]+)&var4=([^&\s]+)&var5=([^&\s]+)&var6=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/%6? [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5&var6=$6&page=$7 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5&var6=$6 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var3=$2&var4=$3&var5=$4&var6=$5 [L,QSA]
```

URL's 1,2 and 4 are working, however URL number 3 is being read as:

```
 3.  RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?var2=$1&var3=$2&var4=$3&var5=$4&var6=$5 [L,QSA]
```

What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can match the 2nd perameter optionally in your condition and  Rule's pattern :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\?var1=([^&\s]+)(?:&var2=([^&\s]*/?))?&var3=([^&\s]+)&var4=([^&\s]+)&var5=([^&\s]+)&var6=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index/%1/%2%3/%4/%5/%6? [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^index/([^/]+)/([^/]*/)?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4&var5=$5&var6=$6&page=$7 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: should I have just the single `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}` or both?  Can you show a full example for all 4 URL's?

Comment: Internal Server Error